# Autopopulate form based on selected value from combo box with Jquery and Ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax

I am new to ajax and Jquery. I have written the code to autopopulate a combo box by an ajax call in my form that I am designing. Now I want to make rest of the fields of the same form autopoulated based on the selected value from combo box and for that I need another ajax call which will return me only one object of `student`. With this object I can set the fields of the form like this way:

`$('#student_name').val(student.name); 
$('#student_roll_num').val(student.roll_num); etc.`

where name, roll_num are the id of the fields of the form.

I am writing in this following way:

```
//This following function will get called when one value from the combo box is 
//selected

 $("select#student_id").change(function(){
    var student_id = $(this).val(); //Here I am getting the selected value from 
    //the combo box
    $.ajax({
        url: "/students_database?student_id="+student_id, //this is the url that will
        //send me one student object
        dataType: "json",
        success: /*YET TO BE FILLED WITH CODE TO AUTO 
        /* POPULATE REST OF THE FIELDS*/ 
});
```

Actually here I cannot decide how to access the retuned student object so that I can access its fields like above I said. So, if anyone kindly help me to do this, I will be really grateful. Also if there is any better approach please suggest. Thank you.

Comment: can you add the html that you're using and/or make a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you get json of one student from your ajax call, this should work:

```
 $("select#student_id").change(function(){
    var student_id = $(this).val(); //Here I am getting the selected value from 
    //the combo box
    $.ajax({
        url: "/students_database?student_id="+student_id, //this is the url that will
        //send me one student object
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(student) {
           $('#student_name').val(student.name);
           $('#student_roll_num').val(student.roll_num);
        }    
    });
 });
```

Comment: This is not working. I don't understand where the error is occurring. Actually I have filled the combo box with student name. Here when I am using student.roll_num, it is telling that unresolved variable. So how can I access the other members of student object?

Comment: Also according to your approach the student.name and student.roll_num is coming blank even though they are not null

Comment: @Joy, maybe your ajax call doesn't return what you expect? try to print JSON.stringify(student) in the success function to see what is actually returned