# Parsing ajax response in Json format with Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, json

I am new to Jquery and Ajax. I have written the following code to autopopulate a form after clicking a option in a combo box in a form by taking help from this post [Autopopulate form based on selected value from combo box with Jquery and Ajax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18810361/autopopulate-form-based-on-selected-value-from-combo-box-with-jquery-and-ajax):

```
 $("select#student_id").change(function(){
    var student_id = $(this).val(); //Here I am getting the selected value from 
    //the combo box
    $.ajax({
        url: "/students.json?student_id="+student_id, //this is the url that will
        //send me one student object
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(student) {
           $('#student_email').val(student.email);
           $('#student_roll_num').val(student.roll_num);
        }    
    });
 });
```

But all these values `student.email, student.roll_num` are coming blank and when I am issuing the statement `alert(student)`, it is printing `[object object]` like that. But when I am invoking the same json call in the browser I get expected json object of the student where I get correct values for all student attributes. Am I doing wrong anywhere in this above code? So if anybody helps me to fix this, I will be really grateful. Thank you.

Comment: Can you post /students_database action statements?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, this is help you. Here U = Url of Page and F = Function of Page

```
$("select#student_id").change(function(){
        var student_id = $(this).val();   
    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: U + '/' + F,
            data: "{id: " + student_id + "}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            cache: false,
            success: function (response) {
                var content=response.d;
            }
        });
    });
```

Comment: I mean, there are about 30 columns in students table, so do I have to write the column names of all of them in data parameter in ajax call?

Comment: Should your code behind method get properly data from database?